# how to make project 64 bit compatible

Tags: java, android, google-play, 64-bit, android-architecture

Recent changes in android architecture have enforced all developers to make their android applications support 64bit.

I have gone through the documentations. But as it shows there to look for a "lib" folder that may supposedly have ".so" files.

I tried the same thing, but apparently I can't find and "lib" folder to begin with, my app is completely written in java, there is no native(C,C++) code.

Can anyone suggest me what can be done or how can I ensure my apps are 64bit supported or how I will get the lib with .so files.

Comment: If you do not have any C/C++ code, and your dependencies do not have any C/C++ code, you are already set for 64-bit CPUs. [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) explains how you can examine your APK contents to confirm whether any dependencies use native code.

Comment: I followed all the steps given in this document, I evaluated the app using command line there also there is no.so file and I have also used app analyze and dint found any .so file. SO my question is still I am good to go or there should be lib folder with .so file in app to upload on play store. As I read many people also faced same issue and uploaded app but they got email from Google to add 64 bit compatibility.@CommonsWare

Comment: Please share your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

If you have no native (NDK) code, that is you only write Java/Dex code, then you don't need to do anything.

If you have native code (or libraries) then you need to supply their 64-bit versions.

**Detailed answer (explanation):**

Following action is suggested by the Google Play team:

> If you haven't yet, we encourage you to begin work for the 64-bit
>   requirement as soon as possible. Many apps are written entirely in
>   non-native code (e.g. the Java programming language or Kotlin) and
>   will not need code changes.
>
> Please note that we are not making changes to our policy on 32-bit
>   support. Google Play will continue to deliver apps with 32-bit native
>   code to 32-bit devices. The requirement means that those apps will
>   need to have a 64-bit version as well.
>
> To help you make the transition, we've prepared [documentation](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) on how
>   to check whether your app already supports 64-bit and how to become
>   64-bit compliant.
>
> We're also providing a high-level timeline below.

Summarising the documentation link that is provided in the above quoted paragraph:

> If your app uses only code written in the Java programming language or
>   Kotlin, including any libraries or SDKs, your app is already ready for
>   64-bit devices. If your app uses any native code, or you are unsure if
>   it does, you will need to assess your app and take action.
>
> .....
>
> The simplest way to check for 64-bit libraries is to inspect the
>   structure of your APK file. When built, the APK will be packaged with
>   any native libraries needed by the app. Native libraries are stored in
>   various folders based on the ABI. It is not required to support every
>   64-bit architecture, but for each native 32-bit architecture you
>   support you must include the corresponding 64-bit architecture.
>
> For the ARM architecture, the 32-bit libraries are located in
>   armeabi-v7a. The 64-bit equivalent is arm64-v8a.
>
> For the x86 architecture, look for x86 for 32-bit and x86_64 for
>   64-bit.
>
> The first thing to do is ensure that you have native libraries in both
>   of these folders....

**If your APK already has NDK code and 64-bit libraries, follow this:**

> Most Android Studio projects use Gradle as the underlying build
>   system, so this section applies to both cases. Enabling builds for
>   your native code is as simple as adding the arm64-v8a and/or x86_64,
>   depending on the architecture(s) you wish to support, to the
>   ndk.abiFilters setting in your app's 'build.gradle' file:
>
> ```
> // Your app's build.gradle
> apply plugin: 'com.android.app'
>
> // Your app's build.gradle    apply plugin: 'com.android.app'
>
> android {
>    compileSdkVersion 27
>    defaultConfig {
>      appId "com.google.example.64bit"
>      minSdkVersion 15
>      targetSdkVersion 28
>      versionCode 1
>      versionName "1.0"
>      ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'   
> // ...
> ```

I hope this helps.

Comment: . My pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

So if you really want to create .so file in you native java project. Follow below steps:

Step 1 :  To install the NDK, CMake and LLDB, do the following:
With a project open, click Tools > SDK Manager.
Click the SDK Tools tab.
Install NDK, CMake and LLDB.
Step 2 : After these steps create a cpp folder inside project/src/main.

Step 3 : Under cpp folder, add native-lib.cpp.

Step 4 : Create SMakeLists.txt file under project folder.

Step 5 : add externalLibrary in Gradle:

```
android{
     externalNativeBuild {
       cmake {
          path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
     }
```

}

```
defaultConfig {
  ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
  externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        cppFlags ""
    }
}
```

}